What was the original myth later referred to by Arrian that involved Herakles besieging Aornos?
In Arrian's Anabasis IV.21 we have an account of the siege of a fortress known as Aornos. It seems to be located deep within Bactria (present-day Afghanistan/Pakistan).
According to Arrian, Alexander's conquest was all the more remarkable because of a legend that Herakles has once attempted to take the fort and failed. However, we don't seem to have any associations of Herakles and this fort within the extant Herakles myth cycle.
It's possible it was lost over time, or it may have been an outright invention by Arrian Aristobulus for the purposes of narrative structure and embellishment.
Those possibilities in mind, we might still find traces of this myth in surviving ancient sources. For starters, Herakles reaching Asia and sacking cities in Asia can be affirmed by the myth of Herakles sacking Troy (before the Iliad). Perhaps the Herakles besieging Aornos is a regional reflex of the Greek Herakles, such as the Iranian Verethragna/Bahram, whose iconography Bactrian coinage often featured.
Question
Is there a scholarly consensus on what has informed Arrian's suggestion that Herakles participated in an ancient battle at the site of Aornos: presumably he was drawing from an existing myth?

Arrian himself provides a hint regarding the origin of this legend: it arose from the desire to flatter Alexander, to provide "embellishment" as you say:

Any one who receives these stories may believe or disbelieve them as he pleases. But I do not altogether agree with Eratosthenes the Cyrenaean, who says that everything which was attributed to the divine agency by the Macedonians was really said to gratify Alexander by their excessive eulogy. For he says that the Macedonians, seeing a cavern in the land of the Parapamisadians, and hearing a certain legend which was current among the natives, or themselves forming a conjecture, spread the report that this forsooth was the cave where Prometheus had been bound, that an eagle frequented it to feast on his inward parts, that when Heracles arrived there he killed the eagle and set Prometheus free from his bonds. He also says that by their account the Macedonians transferred Mount Caucasus from the Euxine Sea to the eastern parts of the earth, and the land of the Parapamisadians to that of the Indians; calling what was really Mount Parapaniisus by the name of Caucasus, in order to enhance Alexander's glory, seeing that he forsooth had gone over the Caucasus. He adds, that when they saw in India itself some oxen marked with the brand of a club, they concluded from this that Heracles had penetrated into India. Eratosthenes also disbelieves the similar tale of the wandering of Dionysus. Let me leave the stories about these matters undecided as far as I am concerned.
Arrian. The Anabasis of Alexander. Trans. E J Chinnock. V.iii. Accessed at wikisource.org 26 July 2024.

Arrian is here indulging in paraleipsis. By saying he does not entirely agree with Eratosthenes, then stating that he will leave the question undecided, he's making it pretty clear that he does not for a moment believe the story that Herakles tried but failed to conquer Aornos. Strabo makes explicit what Arrian tactfully hints at:

When Alexander, at one assault, took Aornus,​a a rock at the foot of which, near its sources, the Indus River flows, his exalters said that Heracles thrice attacked this rock and thrice was repulsed; and that the Sibae were descendants of those who shared with Heracles in the expedition, and that they retained badges of their descent, in that they wore skins like Heracles, carried clubs, and branded their cattle and mules with the mark of a club. And they further confirm this myth by the stories of the Caucasus and Prometheus, for they have transferred all this thither on a slight pretext, I mean because they saw a sacred cave in the country of the Paropamisadae; for they set forth that this cave was the prison of Prometheus and that this was the place whither Heracles came to release Prometheus, and that this was the Caucasus the Greeks declared to be the prison of Prometheus.
But that these stories are fabrications of the flatterers of Alexander is obvious; first, not only from the fact that the historians do not agree with one another, and also because, while some relate them, others make no mention whatever of them; for it is unreasonable to believe that exploits so famous and full of romance were unknown to any historian, or, if known, that they were regarded as unworthy of recording, and that too by the most trustworthy of the historians; and, secondly, from the fact that not even the intervening peoples, through whose countries Dionysus and Heracles and their followers would have had to pass in order to reach India, can show any evidence that these made a journey through their country. Further, such accoutrement of Heracles is much later than the records of the Trojan War, being a fabrication of the authors of the Heracleia,​ whether the author was Peisander or someone else. The ancient statues of Heracles are not thus accoutred.
Strabo. The Geography. Trans. H. L. Jones. XV.1. Accessed at penelope.uchicago.edu 26 July 2024.

So it seems that by artfully transferring the Caucasus to the Indian subcontinent, the flatterers of Alexander were able to manufacture the myth that Herakles had been in India but failed to conquer Aornos.

In Aeschylus' Prometheus Bound, and in Apollodorus 1.7, there is mention of Herakles in the Caucasus, en route to liberate Prometheus, however I haven't encountered any sources that detail Herakles' struggles while in the Caucasus. Have you seen any sources where Herakles sacks cities while in the Caucasus? That would probably help us see the link Strabo seems to be asserting.

I don't believe there are any sources that show Herakles struggling in the Caucasus, which is why the story that Aornos equates to Caucasus, and that Alexander won there without a struggle, is taken to be flattering fiction. Strabo is following Eratosthenes in this. Should I edit to make that clearer?

I get the flattering fiction part, and I get that some sources either confused or purposefully misplaced the geography. Your answer seems fine, in all fairness. Just trying to pinpoint which parts were which: Herakles in the Caucasus has support in the myth cycle. Herakles struggling does not. So it is the "struggling/failing" component that seems to be the invention. It also seems odd to choose a fort for Herakles to sack if the fort had no ties into any where else in the myth cycle
